# Integration Nightmares | Wordpress | Advanced Custom Fields | TM Extra Product Options | WooCommerce Integrations

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I need some severe help moving forward with a clients site.

We are trying to make it easy for him to edit his menu items by giving him one area in a field group with Custom Fields plugin to edit.

We are calling the `[acf ]` shortcode values into the TM Extra Product Options checkbox options string.

This works until the order process and the mail deliver process, where the short code is not parsed into the string, due to some woo commerce defaults.. but further more , TM does not allow for any `<?php ?>` in the string field.

SO id like to know if its possible to reparse code thats in a string some how.

```
`field="<?php do_shortcode ('[act]'); ?>"
```

I have tried other variaties

```
 [acf field="smart_breakfast_day_1" post_id="option"] 
 [acf field="smart_lunch_day_1" post_id="option"] 
 [acf field="smart_dinner_day_1" post_id="option"] 

 <div><?php echo do_shortcode('[acf field="smart_breakfast_day_1" post_id="option"]'); ?></div> 

 <?php $variable = get_field('smart_breakfast_day_1', 'option'); ?> 

 <?php Smart = get_field(smart_breakfast_day_1, options); ?>
```

Nothing works..